# O moderador pode ser especializado em determinadas atividades?

Tags: debate, eleição

Já que são três moderadores a serem eleitos, é permitido que cada um deles se especialize em alguma atividade? claro observando a distribuição de tarefas e de comum acordo entre eles?

Comment: Não vejo problemas nisso, e posso dizer que não é proibido. Mas é algo que, se o grupo de moderadores quiser fazer, precisa partir deles próprios.

Answer (score 16):

A resposta oficial é **não**.

O grupo de moderadores tem poderes iguais e responsabilidades iguais. Isso não significa que todos agirão da mesma maneira. Cada pessoa tem sua própria filosofia de moderação e maneira de agir quanto ao site. Algumas pessoas gostam de participar bastante do Meta; Outras pessoas dedicam mais tempo às sinalizações no site. É possível até mesmo que os moderadores cheguem a um acordo informal sobre a divisão das tarefas mas, oficialmente, os 3 moderadores agem como um corpo só, ainda que independentes uns dos outros.

Isso não significa que o grupo de moderadores deve ser homogêneo, de maneira alguma. *Quanto mais diverso o grupo, melhor*. Quanto mais ideias diferentes de dentro da comunidade eles representarem, melhor. Essa é uma das maneiras mais eficazes de garantir uma moderação justa do site, já que grande parte das decisões foi avaliada sob diversos pontos de vista distintos. Os moderadores podem, inclusive, discordar publicamente entre sí e buscar opiniões da comunidade sempre que necessário.

Quando o Stack Exchange escolhe os moderadores temporários, existe uma "regra" básica dos tipos de pessoas que escolhemos:

- **Especialista do site**
  É alguém que tem demonstrado conhecimento sobre a plataforma do Stack Overflow e a rede Stack Exchange. Que tem experiência com as regras, normas, costumes e história. Que seria capaz de apresentar um ponto de vista baseado no passado da rede, nas coisas que já foram discutidas, etc.
- **Especialista no assunto**
  É alguém que tenha um conhecimento amplo sobre o tema do site (no caso, programação). Que é plenamente capaz de avaliar o conteúdo das perguntas e respostas e julgar se são ou não pertinentes. Que pode ver temas mais obscuros e fazer um julgamento sobre o mérito ou não da pergunta ou resposta.
- **Macaco do Caos**
  É a pessoa responsável por duvidar dos outros 2. Serve pra "atrapalhar" o processo, sendo o advogado do Diabo. Alguém que pode apresentar um ponto de vista totalmente divergente, mas que é importantíssimo pra garantir que as decisões tomadas pela moderação sejam sempre bem ponderadas.

Claro que esses 3 papéis não são mutuamente exclusivos. Mas cada pessoa tem seus pontos positivos, e negativos, e é importante escolher um grupo que se complemente e trabalhe bem em conjunto.

Comment: é importante constar que não levantei a questão de agir sozinho, sem dúvida os três devem representar o corpo de moderação, e claro a proposta do site em questão.

Comment: Excelente filosofia @Gabe. Por isso é que os sites SE funcionam tão bem.