# Eu sei exatamente o que eu estava fazendo 3 anos atrás

Tags: debate

Na imensa maioria das vezes, quando escrevo aqui, falo como *gerente de comunidades*. Estou dando um anúncio, fazendo uma pergunta, iniciando um debate, agindo como "[macaco do caos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3893)"... qualquer coisa que seja necessária nesse cargo, como se "gerenciar uma comunidade" não fosse um oxímoro.

Dessa vez é diferente, escrevo aqui como eu mesmo. Como usuário do site, como programador, como estudante de Ciência da Computação, como Gabe - apelido pelo qual todos os meus amigos me chamam há quase 15 anos.

Pouco mais de 3 anos atrás eu fui contratado pra trabalhar na Stack Exchange (agora Stack Overflow), num projeto semi-secreto que começou alguns meses antes da minha chegada, e que deixou de ser secreto alguns meses depois da minha chegada.

Há exatos 3 anos atrás eu estava sentado numa cadeira branca de plástico, inacreditavelmente desconfortável, na casa dos meus pais, esperando confirmação da equipe de desenvolvimento de que tudo estava nos conformes. Esperando para ver o resultado de meses de reuniões, decisões, emails, discordâncias e problemas **finalmente** tomar forma.

Esperando para ver http://pt.stackoverflow.com **finalmente** ser acessível por mais gente. Endereço que *quase* foi http://br.stackoverflow.com (tanto é que funciona). Endereço que a SE sequer sabia se deveria ser traduzido (estourodepilha.com.br?) ou localizado (stackoverflow.com.br?) até eu chegar e avisar todo mundo que nada disso era necessário.

E foi exatamente 3 anos atrás (no momento em que escrevo essa frase) que isso aconteceu. Que o beta privado do Stack Overflow em Português começou oficialmente. Alguns felizardos, que participaram da nossa proposta na Area 51 entraram um dia antes, com um convite personalizado ao invés do email automático, mas considerem aquela nossa... pré-estreia.

Eu não fazia ideia do que ia acontecer dali pra frente e, falando francamente, ninguém na empresa fazia. Só sabíamos que o trabalho tinha sido árduo até ali e era muito bom ver as primeiras centenas de pessoas, de perguntas e respostas sendo feitas. Mas, especialmente, era a primeira vez que eu tinha uma comunidade para "gerenciar".

E muita coisa aconteceu. Muitas conquistas diferentes. Tivemos eventos, encontros, promoções. Eu tendo que organizar uma festa pra dezenas de pessoas, em outro estado... Sem sequer gostar de festas, ou ter pisado em São Paulo em anos. Aprendi muita coisa em cima da hora, no improviso. Aprendi a conversar com fornecedores, aprendi a falar sobre marketing. Aprendi a planejar orçamentos. Aprendi a pedir recursos e aprendi a dizer não para usuários.

Também aprendi a gerenciar uma comunidade - pelo menos um pouco. Tudo nesses 3 anos.

Aprendi a apagar incêndios. Aprendi a ser criticado, questionado, duvidado e às vezes quase ofendido. Aprendi a ter que acordar no dia seguinte e vir aqui, com o melhor sorriso que eu conseguia pôr na cara, fazer tudo de novo. Porque tinha certeza de que tudo aquilo vinha de pessoas que, assim como eu, queriam que esse site fosse o melhor possível, e servisse à comunidade da melhor maneira possível.

Aprendi a dizer não. E aprendi a **ter** que dizer não. O segundo é muito pior. As coisas que, apesar dos meus melhores esforços, não consegui transformar em realidade no nosso site são mais difíceis de engolir do que ter uma dúzia de programadores indignados comigo porque eu disse não para alguma coisa.

Tudo isso em três anos. Três anos bem agitados.

Alguns dias atrás eu [precisei fazer uma pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/170542) sobre SQL. Já eram 19h no Brasil... bem tarde. Perguntei meio displicente, não era urgente. Não precisava de uma resposta imediatamente. Mas ela veio. Veio só 4 minutos depois. **4 minutos**.

Naquela hora eu sorri. Não porque eu tinha conseguido a resposta do problema, mas porque foi mais uma das várias ocasiões que me mostram porque o SOpt vale a pena. Porque ele é tão valioso. E porque eu mal posso esperar pelos *próximos 3 anos*. Próximos 5, 10...

Vocês são uma comunidade sensacional. Problemática, imprevisível e estressante pra quem tem a tarefa de "gerenciá-los". Mas sensacional. Vocês estão provendo para outros programadores, como vocês, como eu, algo que não tem preço: *conhecimento*.

Algo que, 15 anos atrás enquanto eu aprendia a programar, estava restrito à livros caros e defasados (e, francamente, ruins). Vocês estão criando o fundamento para uma nova geração de programadores que tem de onde tirar conhecimento, apoio, ajuda e compreensão. Gente que pense como eles. Que troque ideias como eles. Vocês estão, mesmo sem saber, aumentando exponencialmente o que a próxima geração pode fazer.

Eu tenho muito orgulho desse lugar.

Parabéns. Feliz 3 anos de vida.

Comment: [♥](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5524/18246)

Comment: Fico feliz em ter você para cuidar do SOpt, vem fazendo um ótimo trabalho. Que venham muitos anos pela frente haha =)

Comment: Obrigado Gabe, você tem feito um ótimo trabalho. E eu tenho muito orgulho de dizer que faço parte desta comunidade e que sou desta geração ;D... Feliz 3 anos de vida \o/

Comment: Aprendi a palavra "oxímoro". Obrigado ;D

Comment: Que legal :), Parabéns! Pelos 3 anos e obrigado por tudo isso.

Answer (score 36):

## Eu *também* sei exatamente o que eu estava fazendo 3 anos atrás

Na imensa maioria das vezes, quando escrevo aqui, falo como um programador experiente e moderador do site. Estou respondendo perguntas dando meu melhor ponto de vista técnico, contribuindo para um debate, sendo o "do contra" para balancear o debate.

Dessa vez é diferente. Escrevo aqui como eu mesmo, um programador que volta e meia esquece o básico, que luta todos os dias para não se perder no mar de novas tecnologias, que volta e meia se sente inseguro ao tomar decisões mesmo quando pequenas... o Luiz.

Há pouco mais de três anos, estava sentado na minha baia, numa pequena empresa próxima à Paulista em São Paulo, inseguro sobre o futuro, ponderando o que fazer para:

- Avançar em minha carreira profissional, além dos livros
- Ter contato com bons profissionais e assim absorver conhecimento
- Colocar meus conhecimentos à prova

Foi nesse período em que comecei a conhecer mais a fundo a então rede Stack Exchange e me inscrevi, meio sem saber o que significava, na proposta da Area 51 para o Stack Overflow em Português. 
Foi então que, dia 23/11/2013, fiquei um tanto surpreso em receber o e-mail do gabe intitulado *"Anunciando... Stack Overflow em português!
"*.

Diferente de outros usuários, eu não sabia muito bem como os sites funcionavam, além do básico de perguntar e responder. Mas foi neste período que conheci uma comunidade brasileira crescente e vibrante.
Alguns meses no beta e percebi como ter saído do meu pequeno círculo profissional foi uma [experiência social muito bem sucedida](http://luizricardo.org/2014/02/resultados-de-um-experimento-social/).

Participando, contribuindo e colhendo feedback, pude atingir aqueles objetivos. Muitas vezes senti orgulho de ver conteúdo de alta qualidade em perguntas e respostas, tanto que comecei a [publicar o conteúdo de algumas respostas em formato de artigo](http://luizricardo.org/2014/02/o-que-sao-e-como-funcionam-transacoes-em-sql/).

Mais do que contribuir para o aperfeiçoamento das habilidades técnicas, tive o grande privilégio de ser apontado e posteriormente eleito como moderador do site, o que me permitiu desenvolver ainda em muitos outros aspectos enquanto contribuía um pouco para o gerenciamento da comunidade.

Após quase um ano participando do Stack Overflow em Português, [tive a honra de conhecer algumas pessoas por trás dos avatares durante o TDC de 2014](http://luizricardo.org/2014/09/stack-overflow-no-tdc-2014/), alguns dos quais levarei como amigos para a vida.

Minha vida mudou bastante desde então. Mudei de [país](http://luizricardo.org/2015/10/hello-australia/) e de [emprego](http://luizricardo.org/2015/11/hello-atlassian/). Tenho certeza de que parte da minha evolução foi uma contribuição do site, mais especificamente de todos aqueles que, perguntando, respondendo e, principalmente, me criticando, fizeram com que eu me tornasse um profissional melhor.

Há um ano, [em outra retrospectiva](http://luizricardo.org/2015/12/porque-nao-acompanho-mais-o-stack-overflow-em-portugues/), fiquei alegre em ver como a comunidade crescia e caminhava cada vez mais rápido, dependendo cada vez menos de alguns poucos usuários mais antigos.

No último ano, estive menos presente no site devido à diversas mudanças profissionais e pessoais, incluindo o nascimento de minha filha Lydia, a quarta da escadinha.

Hoje, fazendo outra retrospectiva, fico muito feliz que a comunidade ainda esteja em contínua evolução sem mim, tendo sido bem cuidado pelos novos moderadores eleitos e pelos novos usuários que contribuem diariamente para o sucesso da comunidade, que na verdade se traduz simplesmente em ter uma comunidade de programadores sadia, crescendo e evoluindo em conjunto.

Sim, temos nossos problemas. Porém, a despeito disto, o Stack Overflow em Português ainda me parece, na maior parte do tempo, um lugar acolhedor e compreensivo para aqueles que realmente procuram ajuda e se deixam ajudar e também para quem quer compartilhar conhecimento.

Meu votos são para que a comunidade cresça cada vez mais e seja cada vez mais acolhedora sem, no entanto, comprometer sua qualidade!

Parabéns!

Comment: Faço minhas as suas palavras. Ainda que eu já tivesse um histórico no SOen quando recebi o e-mail do Beta, ainda tenho muito orgulho de ter meu nome junto a tantas feras lá na Area 51. Quanto ao TDC 2014 (o melhor), eu não sei bem o que é causa e o que é consequência... O que eu sei é que em 2 anos o pessoal que entrou naquele Pub com o Gabe e o Joel já se espalhou por 4 continentes (e contando :)).

Answer (score 26):

A 3 anos atrás eu estava começando a entrar nesse mundo de 0s e 1s, pena que demorei tanto procurando no lugar errado.

Bom, eu não estou a tanto tempo por aqui, apenas alguns meses. Mas, a mais tempo do que isso venho tentando aprender sobre programação, tanto que cheguei a cursar 1 ano em uma faculdade, e infelizmente devido ao nosso infeliz sistema de ensino(ou por que não levo jeito nesse sistema por ser auto-didata), preferi economizar meu tempo e dinheiro,  e investir na minha técnica (autodidatismo) que já me deu bom resultado em outras áreas.

E embora a internet pareça um lugar de infinito conhecimento, foi aqui que encontrei os melhores professores. Não me ensinaram apenas códigos, mas a pensar como programador, a saber realizar perguntas de forma que o aprendizado realmente acontecesse...

Agradeço a quem teve a iniciativa de plantar essa semente e a quem se dispôs a cultivá-la.

E principalmente a aqueles que fazem o SOpt ser, sem medo de estar errado o TOP 1 para nós lusófonos, não sei se lá fora há concorrência, mas aqui certamente as 3 posições do podium tem um SO em um pt.

Valeu :

@bacco
@Guilhermenascimento
@Wallacemaxters
@Sergio
@rray
@Jbueno
@Bigown
@diegofm
@renan
@Ciganomorrinson
@randrade
@stderr
@luisvieira
@marceloandrade
@gato
@alanandrade
@diegoaugusto

E tantos outros que tornariam este muito maior, mas eles estão todos [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users)

Esses agradecimentos não são apenas pelos motivos acima, mas por essas pessoas fazerem deste mundo um mundo melhor e com uma comunidade sem igual.

Abraço de verdade !

Answer (score 18):

朝茶飲む僧静かなり菊の花

*Um monge bebe o chá da manhã; quieto, o crisântemo florescendo.* - [Matsuo Bashō](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matsuo_Bash%C5%8D)

---

A três anos eu tinha acabado de começar a trabalhar na [universidade Bucknell](http://www.bucknell.edu/) após me mudar para os Estados Unidos com esposa e filha. Para a primeira era um retorno para sua terra natal; para mim foi um momento de relativa insegurança. Como me portar em um ambiente de trabalho no exterior? Quais são as espectativas? E, o mais importante - como lidar com os profissionais daqui sem cometer um [faux pas](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deslize)?

O tempo dá solução a tudo. Hoje estou mais integrado ao meu ambiente de trabalho, e cultivo amizades e colaborações.

Minha experiência com o Stack Overflow em Português possui certas similaridades com minha vida profissional. Eu vi seu início, com sua personalidade ainda a ser definida. Eu também questionei se o esforço era válido, mas fui completamente convencido [quando recebi uma resposta válida, aqui, em uma pergunta que não recebeu nenhum feedback no SO principal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276251/1845714).

Hoje o SO-PT é uma criatura com personalidade própria e conteúdo de qualidade, onde cultivo contatos, amizades e colaborações ([Nyan](https://github.com/bucknellu/Nyan) e [SOClearChat](https://github.com/lbotinelly/SOClearChat), por exemplo, receberam contribuições de vários membros), onde os posts poéticos do Mestre Programador são bem recebidos, e um chat onde compartilhamos nosso dia a dia.

A três anos atrás eu presenciei o nascer do SO-PT.
O tempo passa, e a comunidade evolui; quieto e contente, observo-o florescer.

Answer (score 17):

## Eu sei. Sim, programando em Java

Era final de 2013 e eu não exatamente era um usuário assíduo do Stack Overflow. Era um empresário recém-consolidado, sem grandes projetos, com um convite para trabalhar em São Paulo para ASP.NET MVC. Não ganhava muito. Era muito esforçado e tinha um pequeno projeto que me serviu para estudar e aprender os conceitos que hoje domino.

Já estava cansado do Java. O ASP.NET MVC estava na versão 4 e prestes a lançar a versão 5 que, na data dessa resposta, ainda é a versão estável do ASP.NET MVC (o Core é quase estável, mas possui poucas bibliotecas já convertidas para o novo modelo de Assembly e isso ainda deve demorar um pouco mais). Queria também programar Python, Ruby, Groovy, Scala, umas coisas mais modernas. Todas as ideias que eu tinha que repaginar o produto em que eu trabalhava foram negadas, então a opção que eu tinha era virar a página.

Me estabeleci em São Paulo no novo cliente e, alguns dias depois, entre algumas pesquisas, começaram a aparecer uns anúncios em português. Era uma comunidade do Stack Overflow, em Português, em Beta. Era dia 30 de janeiro de 2014. A comunidade estava jovem e pouca gente respondia ASP.NET MVC. Ganhei meus primeiros 101 pontos (por ser um usuário antigo do SO) e comecei. De cara já notei que a comunidade era diferente. Não havia o espírito destrutivo de competição e excesso de zelo que vejo no SO desde aquela época (ainda vejo um pouco hoje, dependendo da *tag*), em que os usuários preferem julgar se sua resposta está escrita do jeito que eles gostam, se é relevante do ponto de vista deles e assim por diante, com o manual de regras embaixo do braço. Sendo uma comunidade mais permissiva e tolerante, a recepção de novos usuários foi maior e a comunidade cresceu a olhos vistos.

O SOpt virou meu cartão de visitas para o mundo. Muitas perguntas me fizeram voltar a estudar. Muitas respostas me mostraram que eu precisava reciclar muito conhecimento. Escrevi um livro e um curso, que virou uma tutoria, consegui uma oportunidade de trabalho nos EUA (além de outras oportunidades em países como Holanda, Suécia e Reino Unido, que ficaram no quase) e virei MVP da Microsoft (o certificado está a caminho, pelo correio, aliás). Tive um ganho profissional impressionante, que pontos de reputação não traduzem corretamente. Eu ajudo o site. O site me ajuda.

Pelo menos em ASP.NET MVC o site é referência nacional no Brasil, contrariando as correntes de desenvolvimento que são senso comum. Somos o maior contraponto. O curso que desenvolvi é apenas a síntese de todo o material que está aqui, e que atrai interessados a cada dia.

Agora estou querendo desenvolver um *coaching* para os usuários do site. Sinto que boa parte não entende a força que o site tem, e que pouquíssimos sabem vender o peixe. Quando quero contratar aqui, tenho dificuldades. Fica a dica pra vocês melhorarem seus perfis, pelo menos possibilitando uma forma de entrar em contato.

No mais, voltei a programar em Java, por sinal, na mesmíssima atividade que eu exercia em 2013, e com a mesma empresa. Que fique registrado.

Comment: Se precisar de um coaching ou consulting na área de confecção, esse é o contato de um mestre 777alisson777@gmail.com, em programação ainda estou engatinhando .... heheh

Answer (score 7):

Aprendo muito aqui fico feliz por isso !

Answer (score 6):

A 3 anos atrás eu consegui meu primeiro emprego, como estagiário em TI.
Sempre acompanhei e admirei o StackOverflow. Acabei não acompanhando o StackOverflow em Português não como nesse ultimo ano, mas sempre acompanhei as comunidades, mesmo não participando diretamente.

É um orgulho ter uma comunidade na linguagem portuguesa. Estamos construindo uma MENTE que acredito facilitar e adiantar muita tarefa dos futuros desenvolvedores. Tanto porque, não adianta olhar apenas para o seu caminho, o teu sucesso. Pra você desenvolver hoje com um git da vida, um SO decente, foram MUITOS nerds ralando para facilitar o nosso dia a dia. Ajudar o próximo faz parte da vida de um programador.

Comment: Em tese a comunidade é lusófona, nossos amigos portugueses também são muito presentes e essenciais para o bom funcionamento :-]

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Eu só trocaria "Em tese ..." por "Na verdade ...". Apesar de, em termos comparativos, o número de participantes não brasileiros ser reduzido, [desde cedo ficou decidido que seria uma comunidade lusófona](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/50/2541).

Comment: @ramaral você tem razão, é um vício de linguagem que eu tenho xD... desculpas?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Não tem que pedir desculpa. Eu não tive dúvida do que você pretendia dizer. Apenas quis salientar que isso foi discutido no início.